# Как получить значение вложенного тега по клику на кнопку?

Tags: javascript

имеются кнопки

```
<button type="button" class="sklad mb-2"><div>склад1</div><span> пн-вс 10:00 - 19:00</span></button>
<button type="button" class="sklad mb-2"><div>склад2</div><span> пн-вс 10:00 - 19:00</span></button>
<button type="button" class="sklad mb-2"><div>склад3</div><span> пн-вс 10:00 - 19:00</span></button>
<button type="button" class="sklad mb-2"><div>склад4</div><span> пн-вс 10:00 - 19:00</span></button>
```

Как получить значение внутри тега **div** по нажатию на кнопку (**button**)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.sklad');
buttons.forEach((element, i) => {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {        
        console.log(buttons[i].querySelector('div').textContent);
    });
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="sklad mb-2"><div>склад1</div><span> пн-вс 10:00 - 19:00</span></button>
<button type="button" class="sklad mb-2"><div>склад2</div><span> пн-вс 10:00 - 19:00</span></button>
<button type="button" class="sklad mb-2"><div>склад3</div><span> пн-вс 10:00 - 19:00</span></button>
<button type="button" class="sklad mb-2"><div>склад4</div><span> пн-вс 10:00 - 19:00</span></button>
```

Comment: А зачем тебе `buttons[i]`? Почему не сразу `element`?)

Comment: Если element, то будет обрабатываться тот элемент, куда кликнули. А это может быть и div и span, помимо button

Comment: Я так же подумал и потому поэкспериментировал с `element` перед тем как написать, но всё работало как надо, потому и спросил)

Comment: А у меня что-то не работало ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯   вроде должно было работать всплытие, но что-то не получилось